# Switching to Linux to fix BSOD?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, bsod

I've been bouncing updating drivers, system restores, and other troubleshooting methods - laptop just keeps throwing BlueSODs, and I've in general had it with Window's endless stream of bugs despite my "clean" usage. Assuming the problems aren't hardware-related, but *are* possibly driver-related, could simply switching to a Linux distribution resolve the BSODs? (If it's driver-related, I'm hoping Linux has better system-managed driver updating than Windows.)

---

**SMART scan results**: (temp sometiems reads "very high" though within 56-58)

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking if Linux will be using the same drivers that Windows does, thus suffering from the same driver issues? Have you tried any standard BSOD troubleshooting methods, like looking up error codes or analyzing memory dumps?

Comment: @gronostaj Maybe some BSODs are unique to Windows or caused by Windows-related problems, is what I'm asking. And yes I've tried troubleshooting per error codes, but not memory dumps as those aren't generated (tried troubleshooting _that_ also).

Comment: You've tried system restore and "other troubleshooting methods", have you tried a clean install from a freshly created media?

Comment: @Mokubai No, that's a "last resort" as I first need to back up my 1TB of data to a hard disk I don't have (or cloud I haven't rented), as I presume you refer to a complete Windows reinstall. But I've done that several times in the past and BSODs have returned shortly-after, but only during certain applications (a game) - now BSOD happens anytime anywhere, and much more frequently. Hence why I'm considering just switching to Linux.

Comment: Well, if you don't like to pay homage to BSOD's then switching to Linux is a good option.

Comment: Well, BSODs are low-level operating system errors - they stem from the OS architecture. Different OS won't have the same architecture and the same error handling. Still, these errors are caused by _something_ and this something may not be Windows-specific (it's probably not). Run 2 passes of memtest86 and check disk's SMART.

Comment: @gronostaj Ran 5 passes (4 in a row, 1 separately), 0 errors. On SMART, does the D (non-system) drive matter? I ran on C's SSD with native Samsung Magician. I'm also suspecting the GPU and heat management; any tests you can recommend for those?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show us SMART results for the SSD. Overheating shouldn't cause BSODs.

Comment: Yes, switching might help.. but probably not.  This is because of BSODs (aka kernel faults) ***don't stem from OS architecture***.  Very misleading.  BSODs stem from hardware ***or software/drivers*** failing within the kernel because those things are crashing within the same process space as the (ring0) kernel itself.  Windows and Linux kernel programmers both skipped using [rings 1 and 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) which might have changed this.  Linux has different drivers than Windows so if there is a bug in a driver on one and not the other.. switching might help..

Comment: Also.. it is unlikely that you are seeing a bug in a software/driver that nobody else is.  Your problem is probably hardware.